# Suspend/Resume Lenovo

Tags: nvidia, suspend, screen, lenovo, resume

I have occasionally problem with ubuntu 14.10(or 14.04), when I wake up from sleeping, screen remains black. My notebook is Lenovo IdeaPad Z50-70 and graphics is NVIDIA GeForce GT 840M 4GB. Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem here :-( GNOME UBUNTU 14.10

Comment: found only this wiki page of possible solutions/workagrounds for thinkpads http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_display_remaining_black_after_resume

Comment: Duplicate Issues:   http://askubuntu.com/questions/625942/lenovo-z50-70-not-resuming-after-hibernation/630992#630992
     http://askubuntu.com/questions/586387/laptop-doesnt-wake-up-after-puting-it-to-suspend-using-ubuntu-14-10/597589#597589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been reported all over, dunno why it's not being addressed for over a year: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1528735