# Lenovo z50/70 Laptop doesn't wake up after suspend running Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: suspend

Once my laptop goes to suspend, it doesn't wake up.
I can see the LED lights saying that PC is on but screen remains black.

I am really new to Ubuntu and just recently installed it.

My laptop is Lenovo z50/70

Using Ubuntu 14.10 - haven't really done any customization on it.

Comment: same problem here (GNOME UBUNTU 14.10)

Comment: [You should try this if you haven't fixed it yet](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend/436389#436389)

Comment: Mathlight reported in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586387/lenovo-z50-70-laptop-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend-running-ubuntu-14-10#comment1077900_597589) that the answer to the linked post worked for them on this device.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by my Nvidia Graphic card. For some reason (driver issue maybe?) it caused freezing. Disabling the card from BIOS solved the issue.

The problem still persists; maybe changing driver will solve it. I haven't tried.

Comment: Can't speak for your case specifically, but in mine (Linux Mint 20.1, GTX 1060), the driver was the issue. I assumed it was the kernel, not gonna lie, but reverted from 460.<whatever, don't remember> to 450.102, and it works again. Mildly annoying

Answer (score 0):

Lenovo Z50-70, Suspend and hibernate works perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04. After a fresh install of 14.10, resume from suspend (and hibernate) always fails. I was unable to find any solution, so I completely disabled the suspend option on my laptop.

This is not a ideal solution but prevents the accidental suspend and hibernate.

Edit: June 1, 2015.

Found the solution on another forum.
Technically speaking Z50-70 has two GPU's, Intel & nvidia. If nvdia is the default GPU, suspend and hibernate will have issues.

1. Run "nvidia-settings" on terminal.
2. In "PRIME Profiles" tab, select the GPU as "Intel" instead of "NVIDIA".
3. Save and restart your machine.

src: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278513&highlight=z50-70

Comment: thank you for reply, but as you said, this is workaground not a solution of that problem :-(

Comment: Before you do the above, first try [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend/436389#436389) given on an another question.  That worked for me (Lenovo Z50 70), which isn't disabling the NVidea