# Lenovo Z50-70 not resuming after hibernation

Tags: suspend, lenovo, hibernate

My lenovo z50-70 is not resuming after i put the laptop in hibernation mode.

It gives a black screen on resume.
I tried a solution - https://askubuntu.com/a/436389/411863

but it didn't work out.

ram-4 Gb
swap partition size - around 10 Gb

Output for sudo blkid

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="EE5C-6E50" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="DEBE1A3ABE1A0C21" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="B0F6F0A7F6F06ECA" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="F678E7CB78E788A7" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="a0d527cc-6ba9-43c3-93b3-1a6df6391c63" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="c9e8482f-fe43-4c19-8d80-a268c5997690" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda8: UUID="0BF910C10BF910C1" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda9: UUID="0B9305A40B9305A4" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sr0: LABEL="Z40-70DriverV1.1" TYPE="iso9660" 


sid@sid-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
RESUME=UUID=c9e8482f-fe43-4c19-8d80-a268c5997690

sid@sid-Lenovo-Z50-70:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=a0d527cc-6ba9-43c3-93b3-1a6df6391c63 /               ext4           errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c9e8482f-fe43-4c19-8d80-a268c5997690 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there some information. Do you have a swap partition? What is its size? What is size of RAM? Add output of "sudo blkid" , "cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume" and "cat /etc/fstab"

Comment: Output for the last 2 is giving 'no such file or directory'.

Comment: Do not retype commands, but copy them and paste to terminal. No quotes there.

Comment: Sorry! Done as you said

Comment: All is correctly configured. I have no answer. I am sure someone will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible Duplicate of [Laptop doesn't wake up after puting it to suspend - using ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586387/laptop-doesnt-wake-up-after-puting-it-to-suspend-using-ubuntu-14-10/597589#597589)

Found the solution on another forum. Technically speaking Z50-70 has two GPU's, Intel & nvidia. If nvdia is the default GPU, suspend and hibernate will have issues.

1. Run "nvidia-settings" on terminal.
2. In "PRIME Profiles" tab, select
   the GPU as "Intel" instead of "NVIDIA".
3. Save and restart your machine.

src: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278513&highlight=z50-70

Comment: Before you do the above, first try [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend/436389#436389) given on an another question.  That worked for me (Lenovo Z50 70), which isn't disabling the NVidea

Answer (score 2):

[WORKAROUND]

It's possible disable Nvidia graphics under BIOS in Lenovo laptops like Z40-70.

To do procede:

1. Press FN + F2 to in BIOS Configuration
2. Under Configuration in Graphic Device change

   Discrete

to

```
UMA Only
```

This will disable NVIDIA graphics and Suspend will works on Debian, Ubuntu and derived Linux flavors. Not's the best, but is a option.